facet_wrap parse error when using greater than or equal to symbol
I am trying to change the title of two plots made using facet_wrap(), one of which has a greater than or equal to symbol (>=). I can get the plots to parse the title, but as soon as I put the >= symbol in parenthesis, the titles fail to parse. How can I get the titles to parse when the >= symbol is in parenthesis?
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(size = ifelse(hp >= 100, 'greater', 'lesser'),
         size = factor(size, levels = c("greater", "lesser"),
                       labels = c("Horsepower >= 100", "Horsepower < 100"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~size, labeller = label_parsed)


Fails to parse when putting >= in parenthesis.

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(size = ifelse(hp >= 100, 'greater', 'lesser'),
         size = factor(size, levels = c("greater", "lesser"),
                       labels = c("Horsepower (>= 100)", "Horsepower (< 100)"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~size, labeller = label_parsed)
#> Error in parse(text = as.character(values)): <text>:1:13: unexpected '>='
#> 1: Horsepower (>=
#>                 ^

Created on 2024-11-18 with reprex v2.1.1

ggtext package lets you use markdown in ggplot2 labels, which is another way to solve the problem

1) Ensure that the labels are valid R:
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(size = ifelse(hp >= 100, 'greater', 'lesser'),
         size = factor(size, levels = c("greater", "lesser"),
                       labels = c("Horsepower ~ '('>= 100*')'", 
                                  "'Horsepower (< 100)'"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~size, labeller = label_parsed)


2) Another approach is to use unicode 2265 for >=.  In that case omit labeller=...
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(size = ifelse(hp >= 100, 'greater', 'lesser'),
         size = factor(size, levels = c("greater", "lesser"),
                       labels = c("Horsepower (\u2265 100)", 
                                  "Horsepower (< 100)"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~size)



This is helpful but the >= should be one character not two. See how >= looks in the first plot.

Have fixed code

You can use phantom:
plot(1, main = expression(Horsepower ~ (phantom()>= 100)))



I had tried that but it inserts a space after the (

@G.Grothendieck I think there always thin(?) spaces around the >= symbol.
